# Constraint Check Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to know how I could make sure that the value of  `SecondInstrument` doesn't equal the value in `PrimInstrument` since a musician cannot be good with the same instrument twice. So far, this is what I have tried yet, and I got this error message:

```
02438. 00000 -  "Column check constraint cannot reference other columns"
*Cause:    attempted to define a column check constraint that references
           another column.
*Action:   define it as a table check constraint.
```

Could somebody help me out on this one? ;) Thanks in advance.

---

```
Create table SessionMusician (

Musician_ID number constraint pkSessionMus_Mus_ID Primary Key,

StageName varchar2(30)constraint nnSessionMus_StageName Not NULL,

RealName varchar2(30)constraint nnSessionMus_RealName Not NULL,

PrimInstrument varchar2(30) constraint nnSessionMus_PrimInstrumant Not Null,

SecondInstrument varchar2(30)  Default 'N/A' Constraint
chk_SessionMus_Secinstrument check (SecondInstrument <> PrimInstrument),

CONSTRAINT SessionMusician_unique UNIQUE (StageName,RealName));
```

Comment: You tagged it wrong. `oracle-sqldeveloper` is about the tool, and your question has nothing to do with the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make it an [out-of-line constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#CJADJGEC):

```
CREATE TABLE SessionMusician (
    Musician_ID       NUMBER        CONSTRAINT pkSessionMus_Mus_ID         PRIMARY KEY,
    StageName         VARCHAR2(30)  CONSTRAINT nnSessionMus_StageName      NOT NULL,
    RealName          VARCHAR2(30)  CONSTRAINT nnSessionMus_RealName       NOT NULL,
    PrimInstrument    VARCHAR2(30)  CONSTRAINT nnSessionMus_PrimInstrumant NOT NULL,
    SecondInstrument  VARCHAR2(30)  DEFAULT 'N/A',
    CONSTRAINT SessionMusician_unique       UNIQUE ( StageName, RealName ),
    CONSTRAINT chk_SessionMus_Secinstrument CHECK (SecondInstrument <> PrimInstrument)
);
```